# Tab width in SVG Text elements

Tags: css, svg

Consider this SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
   .code {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    tab-size: 4;
   }
  ]]></style>
 </defs>
<text class="code" fill="black" font-size="16" x="0" y="16">
{
</text>
<text class="code" fill="black" font-size="16" x="0" y="32">
 let r;         
</text>
</svg>
```

When rendered you can see that the tab size is clearly 1 space. How can I fix this? I'm using Chrome which apparently does support [`tab-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/tab-size).

Comment: You will need to add the vendor specific tags `-moz`, `-o` for firefox and opera respectively. `-moz-tab-size: 4;` `-o-tab-size: 4;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG has its own set of CSS attributes. Unfortunately, tab-size is not one of them. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html